# Is it possible to make a background task with SignalR

Tags: signalr

I am using Microsoft SignalR in order to push notification to browsers. Those notifications are triggered by action from other browsers. I want to make a background task which send notification sometimes. For example, at 12:45:21 i want to fire a notification to all connected users, even if they are doing nothing. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 4):

SignalR doesn't give you the ability to run a background task, but if you run are running a background task, there is nothing to stop your task using your SignalR hub to invoke client methods and send any desired notification.

To launch and control your background task, [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) is a flexible library that should help.

Edit to add: Since you've clarified you want to do this in a windows service, another prominent library to assist with building and deploying services is [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com/)

Edit to add: Also, I gather from your comment that you're trying to understand how to access the hub object from your background task?  There are many ways to do this, but to improve testability and maintainability of your program, I recommend using an IoC ([Inversion of Control](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)) container, and injecting the necessary references - this tutorial: [Dependency Injection in SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) has a walkthrough using the [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) library.  That walkthrough is oriented towards asp.net hosting, but the link you found should help with adapting to a windows service.

Comment: Do you think it is easy to write a windows service that sends informations to signalR ?

Comment: I think i have found something: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SignalR-self-hosted-in-6ff7e6c3/sourcecode?fileId=116569&pathId=163103385 Do you think this can work for my problem ?

Comment: In fact what I want to know is: In the case of self host signal R program, how can I put a timer in main program and access to hub?

Comment: Yes, you can, like Chris said, nothing is stopping you from having your background task in this case your timer task call your hub to broadcast a message to your clients.

Comment: Edit to add some tips on windows service, and IoC container to obtain a reference to a hubconnectiontcontext

Comment: You really need to use caution with using IoC with signalr most of the time it is not reliable, and there are no real answers as to why this is... lots of discussion, but its mostly opinion and debate, but the bottom line is IoC does not provide reliable delivery of messages. I have personally experienced this myself.

Comment: Interesting - do you have a reference? We're using it on a project at the moment without problems - however we inject the `IConnectionManager` into a singleton service and call `GetHubContext` in the constructor to get a reference.  Has been working so far - but  perhaps we just haven't been observant enough!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using asp.net core 2.1, this is now possible using BackgroundService/IHostedService

https://github.com/davidfowl/UT3/blob/fb12e182d42d2a5a902c1979ea0e91b66fe60607/UTT/Scavenger.cs#L9-L40
(Contents below)

```
public class Scavenger : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<UTTHub> _hubContext;
        private readonly ILogger<Scavenger> _logger;
        public Scavenger(IHubContext<UTTHub> hubContext, ILogger<Scavenger> logger)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // Mark games that haven't played in a while as completed
                var changed = Game.MarkExpiredGames();

                // Mark completed games as removed
                var removed = Game.RemoveCompletedGames();

                if (removed > 0)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Removed {GameCount} games.", removed);
                }

                if (removed > 0 || changed)
                {
                    await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("GameUpdated", Game.GetGames());
                }

                await Task.Delay(5000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also see this
https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/8925